# Slow AES decryption in Android

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I tried to decrypt a 4.2 MB .dcf file using AES 128 bit key, but it took 33 seconds to decrypt (on function cipher.doFinal(data)), is it normal ?

Here is a code snippet:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
            try {
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivspec);

                 android.util.Log.d("TEST", "Start decoding...." + String.valueOf(length));

                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(content);

                File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.mp3");
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                os.write(decrypted);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;

            android.util.Log.d("TEST","Time "+ String.valueOf(end-start));
```

Comment: I expect this will depend on the hardware - my Desire does certain things a lot quicker than my wife's Wildfire, for example. What are you trying this on?

Comment: @MisterSquonk, I tried it on emulator, it took about 30-33 secs, on my Samsung Galaxy Spica, it took about 25-30 secs.

Comment: If you explain how I'd create such a file as the one you're decrypting, I'll try your code on my HTC Desire (Froyo) if it would be of any use to you to know the results.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: I've tried on my friend's N1, it took only 2s. You're right, it depends on hardware and froyo (with jit compiler)

Comment: Wow, that's quite a big difference. Interesting to know, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to bench the time taken without the file writing, i.e. call `System.currentTimeMillis()` right before and right after the call to `cipher.doFinal()`.

That being said, an Android-based phone typically uses a recent ARM processor clocked at 500 MHz or more, and such a beast is theoretically able to AES-encrypt or AES-decrypt several megabytes worth of data per second.

*However*, Android code uses an almost-Java virtual machine called [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29). Prior to Android-2.2, this is an interpreter (no JIT compiler), which means that it is kinda slow for computing-intensive tasks. *If* the mediocre performance you observe really comes from the AES operation itself (and not the file writing) *then* the plausible answer is that your VM provides an AES implementation that is written in Java and interpreted with Dalvik. In that case, there is little cure except hoping for the presence of a better VM implementation (a VM could use a native code implementation for AES; also, with Android 2.2 and later, Dalvik has a [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) which should boost performance of code execution).

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanx for your answer. I have removed the file writing and it took about 30-33 seconds on cipher.doFinal function on froyo emulator or 25-30 secs on Samsung Galaxy Spica (eclair). My friend did the the same task on Blackberry and it took about 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no way to get access to the ARM chip's AES encryption/decryption hardware via the Android APIs :-(

This is a huge oversight on Google's part unfortunately...makes using AES on other platforms a *LOT* faster....